# Laravel connection timeout when connecting to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am moving an application from my development machine to a test server. When connecting to my local development mysql database everything works as expected. When attempting to connect to our test server, the requests time out after 45 seconds and a 500 error is returned.

I tested that the servers can communicate and php can get results by using the basic mysqli php functionality, and results are returned as expected:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo var_export($row, true);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

The following both fail and hit timeout limits in laravel:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();

$users = User::all();
```

Thoughts? Ideas? Opinions?

Comment: The first is just an attempted connection. The second retrieves all the records from the User table. They don't compare. Try `select * from users` in the mysql command line and see how long it takes. Then try some logging -- turn on mysql's slow log and/or general_log for the duration of the test.

Comment: @aynber Updated question after researching your comment

Comment: Next step is to find out if it's just the table, or all DB queries using those methods. Try `DB::select("SELECT NOW()");` and see if that times out. Then `DB::select("SHOW TABLES");` and `DB::select("DESCRIBE users");`

Comment: @aynber The result is the same for each of the select statements you have suggested.

Comment: If those queries are timing out, especially the select now, there's definitely an issue between laravel and your DB. Did you run your mysqli script on the same server as the laravel app, with the exact same credentials?

Comment: @aynber I did. I also created one using pdo and it works as well...i'm quite confused. Going to see if anything is turning up in mysql logs.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. I did `var_dump(DB::connection());` and found out that the host value was wrong because a wrong .env file was loaded.