# Laravel php artisan migrate command - no errors and no console output?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, homebrew

I recently did a fresh install of mysql 8.0.19 via homebrew on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I can see that the mysql service is started when I do `brew services list`. I can also login via the console with `mysql -u root` and execute queries and whatnot.

I've installed a fresh Laravel project using Valet but cannot run database migrations. My environment variables all look to be correct:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I can connect to MySQL Workbench using this information (no root pw). Yet, whenever I run `php artisan migrate` I get no errors and no console output whatsoever. It just gets stuck. Same thing happens when I go in with `php artisan tinker` and then `DB::connection()->getPdo()`. No output and no errors. Nothing gets logged in `storage/logs` either.

Relevant `config/database.php`:

```
...

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


'connections' => [


    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],

],

...
```

Dumping `DB::connection()` on a random view yields the correct config:

```
protected 'config' => 
    array (size=15)
      'driver' => string 'mysql' (length=5)
      'host' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
      'port' => string '3306' (length=4)
      'database' => string 'laravel' (length=7)
      'username' => string 'root' (length=4)
      'password' => string '' (length=0)
      'unix_socket' => string '' (length=0)
      'charset' => string 'utf8mb4' (length=7)
      'collation' => string 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci' (length=18)
      'prefix' => string '' (length=0)
      'prefix_indexes' => boolean true
      'strict' => boolean true
      'engine' => null
      'options' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'name' => string 'mysql' (length=5)
```

Comment: did you try other artisan commands?

Comment: Yes something like `php artisan make:policy Foobar` works as expected. I can also load views in the browser just fine, just no DB interaction.

Comment: are you sure your `env` file overwrites your config file?

Comment: Looks like it, `php artisan tinker` and `env('DB_DATABASE', 'foobar')` shows the correct info from the `.env` file. The `config/database.php` file also looks correct.

Comment: to be sure try to copy the same infos from `env` file to `config\database.php` file

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant but to verify I went to one of my views and dumped the `DB::connection()` to make sure the env variables were coming through as expected. Weird thing is when I `var_dump(DB::connection()->getPdo());` I get a 504 timeout in the browser.

Comment: Did you tried to restart the mysql service

Comment: Yes I have run `brew services restart mysql` several times.

Comment: can you post your `config\database.php` file?

Comment: in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303802/laravel-connection-timeout-when-connecting-to-database its written that laravel loads the wrong env file. Maybe its your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted running a simple `new mysqli(...)` on a plain PHP script and it failed as well, so it wasn't a Laravel thing.

After doing some more research on this, the solution was just to downgrade my PHP/MySQL versions. I was using PHP 7.4+ and MySQL 8+. I've now rolled back to PHP ~7.3 and MySQL ~5.7.

I came across [this recent thread](https://discourse.brew.sh/t/homebrew-php-7-4-upgrade-fails-on-macos-10-15-1-catalina/6372) which detailed the problem. Something having to do with a new default MySQL authentication plugin. I attempted manually changing it in the database as detailed in that thread as well as [here](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-and-mysql-8-fixing-mysql-server-has-gone-away-error) but didn't have any luck.

Rolling back was easiest for me, thanks everyone!